# c++ copy assignment operator for reference object variable

Tags: c++

I give the following example to illustrate my question:

```
class Abc
{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

};

class Def
{
public:
    const Abc& abc_;

    Def(const Abc& abc):abc_(abc) { }

    Def& operator = (const Def& obj)
    {
        // this->abc_(obj.abc_);
        // this->abc_ = obj.abc_;
    }
};
```

Here I do not know how to define the copy assignment operator. Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can't be done. If you want to make `Def` assignable, have it contain a pointer, not a reference.

Comment: ^^^ Case and point: [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)

Comment: You *can* use a copy constructor to achieve the result you want.  But you can't do it with assignment because reference members can only be set during construction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

references cannot be assigned to. You need something that can. A pointer would work, but they're very abusable.

How about `std::reference_wrapper`?

```
#include <functional>

class Abc
{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

class Def
{
public:
    std::reference_wrapper<const Abc> abc_;

    Def(const Abc& abc):abc_(abc) { }

    // rule of zero now supplies copy/moves for us

    // use the reference
    Abc const& get_abc() const {
      return abc_.get();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

A reference cannot be assigned. Due to this, one can only define it via placement new and copy construction:

```
Def& operator = (const Def& obj)
{
      this->~Def(); // destroy
      new (this) Def(obj); // copy construct in place
}
```

But it is really unnecesary. Just use a pointer.

Comment: `Abc` looks assignable. Couldn't the OP just assign instead of using placement new?

Comment: *Yuck*. This is both clever and awful. +1.

Comment: @StoryTeller this would modify the current `Abc`, not "rebind" the reference.

Comment: @Quentin - I misread it as in place constructing the referenced object... Yikes.
I second your comment to n.m.

Comment: Beyond unnecessary, this is highly dangerous. A class that does this cannot be derived from, because this assignment will blow away the actual type of a derived object.